# How to create a 2D array with variable row and each row has 3 columns?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am thinking like :

```
int i,z[3];
int q[i][z[3]];
```

Can this declaration be right?

If no this suggest a approach where I can store `i` rows and each row have 3 integers in it.

Comment: Array sizes need to be known at compile time.  Try [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Pick a language.  C or C++.

Comment: You can do this trivially using dynamic arrays. (or, use vectors) ^

Comment: Christian says to pick a language.

Comment: He means edit your question so that `c++` is no longer tagged.

Comment: In the comments you seem to have elected for C, but you removed the C tag and retained the C++ tag. Is this correct? Do you want C++ answers?

Comment: Yes it is correct . It is just conceptual, to check if an array have indices as another array.

Comment: Not legal in Standard C++ unless `z` is `constexpr` (`constexpr int z[3] = {10, 20, 30};`) and thus known and fixed at compilation time. If not, Follow @0x5453 's advice. Note: Non- `constexpr` array may be allowed on a compiler-by-compiler basis by a compiler extension. This is  known as a Variable Length Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dbush already mentioned in his answer about *variable-length arrays* (VLAs)

This answer will offer an alternative.

You can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to achieve it:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2d; // 2D vector
int row = 2; // row is variable

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
   vec2d.push_back(std::vector<int>(3)); // each row has 3 columns
}

// just for checking the size
for (auto const& v: vec2d) {
   std::cout << v.size() << " "; // 3 3
                                 // ^ ^ each row has 3 columns
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C supports **variable length arrays** where the array dimensions are determined at run time.

The definition you have for `q` is valid, with the first dimension having size `i` and the second dimension having size `z[3]`.  However since `z` is an array of size 3 its valid indexes are 0 - 2, so the expression `z[3]` reads past the end of the array, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want the second dimension to have size 3, just specify that.

```
int q[i][3];
```

Comment: Got it thanks for explanation. I just made it complex for no use.

Comment: I think he wants to have array z[3] which is defined earlier to be also used as the second dimension of the 2-D array q. If my understanding is correct, there is no straight-forward way that he is looking upto. He needs to do some pointer manipulations to do so.

Comment: I just want to check if- can we give an array of size as an index to 2d array instead of giving integer size.but it seems it is wrong as 2 arrays need not to take occupy continuous memory space.

Comment: @ShivankKashyap Each dimension of an array *must* evaluate to an integer expression.  It doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: @ShivankKashyap, 2-D array also takes continuous memory.